# Reset CSS settings from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to reset the settings of css for an element?
i have an input that I want validate and is not possible because I set the border of text input red but I can't come back to the settings of CSS automatically. is there a way for do it?
thanks in advance.

EDIT 1

```
<input id="tm" type="text" onchange="validateStartTime()" name="orario_start" placeholder="Orario inizio">
```

and `validateStartTime()` is

```
 function validateStartTime(){

        var t_st=document.getElementsByName("orario_start");
        t_st[0].style.borderColor="gray";//HERE I want to set back to the CSS settings automatically
        if(t_st[0].value.length==0){
            t_st[0].style.borderColor="red";
            flag=false;
        }
        //validation time
        var t1=t_st[0].value.split(" ");
        if(t1.length!=2){
            t_st[0].style.borderColor="red";
            flag=false;
        }else{

        var t1_1=t1[0].split(":");
            if(t1_1.length!=2){
                t_st[0].style.borderColor="red";
                flag=false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: have you set the border using javascript?

Comment: Show what you have done to set the border, and what have you tried to reset it

Comment: Quick google of your question title: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506050/how-to-reset-the-style-properties-to-their-css-defaults-in-javascript

Comment: I edited the post the question you @WeatherVane the question you say is  not useful I have a particular setting in CSS.

Comment: why don't you use mousedown event for re setting ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi If you are using jQuery than you can simply change CSS directly :

```
$('#yourElementId').css({
    border : 1px solid #ff0000
});
```

If you are facing issue of removing that red border again than onmousedown you can remove that border.

```
 $('#yourElementId').mousedown(function(){
     $(this).css({
       border : 1px solid white
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) / [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) / or [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) ?

```
$( '#add' ).click( function () {

    $( '#page_navigation1' ).addClass( 'red-class' );

});

$( '#remove' ).click( function () {

    $( '#page_navigation1' ).removeClass( 'red-class' );

});
```

[**Fiddler**](http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingstiff/7w5xv/).