# off boxshadow click button

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hi i have page with video (example-video).
I have button on site, after click site go to dark mode (video is up on darkmode)
Behind the video is boxShadow, now after click dark mode go boxShadow ON and lightning behind video.
But if i close darkmode same button to ON. Go OFF only dark mode, box shadow is stay, how turn off boxShadow with dark mode.

```js
/* show/hide overlay & toggle style of button */
$(".togglelight").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("lightsoff");
  $(".overlay").fadeToggle(700);
  document.getElementById("example-video").style.boxShadow = "#161616 0px 1px 1px 0px inset, #f44336 0px 50px 100px -20px, #f44336 0px 30px 60px -30px";
});
```

```html
<!-- overlay dark-mode -->
<div class="overlay"></div>


<!--BUTTON ON/OFF dark-mode -->
<div class="togglelight" title="title">
  <i class="fas fa-lightbulb"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: dont add the shadow by using `.style` add changes through CSS by using `.classList.toggle`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset the style properties to their CSS defaults in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506050/how-to-reset-the-style-properties-to-their-css-defaults-in-javascript)