# Javascript Auto Reset CSS Styles

Tags: javascript, reset

I have a button that changes an element's style. Can I have this button auto-reset the CSS changed, back to default? Here is the code:

```
<div class="coinboxcontainer"><img id="coin1" src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/coin.png" alt="box" width="40" height="40">
<a onclick="tosscoin()"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/coinbox.png" alt="box" width="40" height="40"></a>
<audio id="audio" src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/coinsound.mp3"></audio>
<script>
function tosscoin() {
       document.getElementById("coin1").style.transform = "translatey(-70px)";
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
}
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset the style properties to their CSS defaults in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506050/how-to-reset-the-style-properties-to-their-css-defaults-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should remove all styles from that element:

```
document.getElementById("coin1").style.cssText = null
```

Resetting styles after some time

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  button.style.transform = `translate(${100}px)`
  setTimeout(() => button.style.cssText = null, 1000)
})
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Though i am looking for a way to do that automatically.. for example after 2 seconds after pressing the button, the styles revert back to normal. Thanks again for your time

Comment: Use `setTimeout`

Comment: Yep tried that already with no luck! I will try more! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To remove css styles from an element using js
Removes all styles.

1. `document.getElementwithSomeMethod.style=null`
2. `document.getElementwithSomeMethod.style.cssText=null`

Remove a single style

1. `document.getElementBySomeMethod.style.removeProperty(propertyName)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, im trying to implement setTimeout to that so that the styles revert to default automatically but i fail